# Laravel relations relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, relationship

I have an understanding issue with Laravel Eloquent Models and relations.

I have a user table `user`. These users can add car license plates, which I save in `user_plates`. I have a database which contains car models and types. The table name is `cars`. I have the models App\User, App\UserPlates and App\Car.

The user_plates table has the fields `id,plate,user_id,car_id`. 
I save the plate, the associated user (in user_id) and the selected car (car_id (id from table cars))

I added `plates()` with `belongTo` function to my User Model which already successfully returns all plates associated with that user. But now I want to get the associated car (car_id inside user_plates). How do I achieve this using Eloquent? The car table does not have any connection to the user table, only user_plates has a car_id and a user_id.

I need to achieve this:
`User -> Plates (can be multiple) -> Plate -> Car`. I know how to achieve this using simple MySQL Joins but I want to do it right with Eloquent. Thanks for any help!

Laravel: 6.4.0

Comment: what about defining a new relation in the UserPlates to the related car?
you will get the car as follow : User #1 > [ plates #1 > car, plates #2 > car ] and so on

Comment: Yes, adding a function car() with $this->belongTo(App\Car) in my UserPlates works, but now I have to iterate through it before I can return it as JSON. Is there any smart way of doing this? I'm pretty new to laravel.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do by iterating over it!

Comment: I have an endpoint which shall return users plates and its associated cars.

Comment: how do you fetch your relations to User model?

Comment: I managed to get it work nearly as I want it.

```return response()->json($request->user()->with('plates.car')->get());```

But as soon as I add "with()" it returns all user, not the $request->user()". But I get the JSON node with Plate + Car

Comment: use the `load` method instead of `with` and you wont need to use `get` so you can do like though `$request->user()->load('plates.car');`

Comment: Thank you hassan, that's it!. I got my Userdata + Plates + Car in a single json. Perfect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if your database is set up as...

```
users   user_plates   cars
-----   -----------   ----
id      id            id
etc.    plate         etc.
        user_id
        car_id
```

Your models are set up as...

```
// in model: User
public function user_plates() 
return $this->hasMany('UserPlate');  // fill out fully qualified name as appropriate…

// in model: UserPlate
public function user() 
return $this->belongsTo('User');

public function car()
return $this->belongsTo('Car');

// in model: Car
public function user_plates()
return $this->hasMany('UserPlate’);
```

To return a collection of cars belonging to user `$id` you should be able to run:

```
$cars = User::findOrFail($id)-> user_plates->pluck('car');
```

Comment: I did add it to my user model, not my controller. This was a mistake in my briefing, thanks for pointing out. I updated it. I did most of the things you've described, but I will double check, because specially $user->cars is what I am looking for, because currently I'm going through the plates to receive the car.

I already played around with hasManyThrough but I could not get it work for me

Comment: The main reason I think I could not make $user->cars work might be the cars table. This is an external, bought one, which only has id, model, make, type, production_year, hsn_tsn as fields. So there is no relation to the user. Only user_plates has a relation to it via user_id and car_id. How would hasManyThrough look like? I think, I have to specify another foreign_key, since "cars" don't have plate_id nor user_id? A small hint to the right direction is highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think Eloquent is going to allow you to set up a hasManyThrough relationship because it seems Eloquent expects there to be a foreign key on the cars table.